# Understanding wager when receiving bonus

Tags: betting

I got a bonus from the betting website I use. What does the following mean?

> To withdraw your bonus, you are required to wager 18 euros with cumulative odds of 1.5 or greater

[image: Here is the message I get]

I have a total of 600 euro, 150 from my money and 450 from the bonuses.

Comment: What part don't you understand?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, How should I make a bet in case to get this wager of 18euro, considering that the cash balance is 150 and the bonus balance is 600 and when I make a bet the betting website uses them both

Comment: The part *"odds of 1.5 or greater"* implies probability of winning lower than 2/3. The *"18 euros"* part is very strange. At least 18 euros? What else did they write?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I have added a picture on how  the message actually looks